# 文字の取り出し方

Tags: python, python2

Python2.7.10/初心者
GitHubからimportしてきた関数についての質問です。
Card('A')この様な関数からAを取り出すには、どの様にすればいいですか。

```
from poker import Card

deck = list(Card)
hand = [deck.pop() for __ in range(2)]
```

このhandに入っているCard('A')です。
返信の回答になっているか分かりませんがよろしくお願いします。

Comment: `Card()`という関数がどう定義されているかわからないと回答ができません。GitHubからimportしたのであれば、どうやってimportしたかを質問に追記してください。

Comment: [Poker package](http://github.com/pokerregion/poker.git) を使っていて、質問欄のコードは [Implementing a deck](https://poker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic.html#implementing-a-deck) でしょうか？

Comment: そうです。そこのコードです　。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

次のように`rank.val`でトランプの数字を`A`のような文字にしたものが取得できます。また、str(Card(u'As').rank)でも同じように取得できます。str(Card(u'As'))とすると'A♠'が取得できるのでstr(Card(u'As'))[0]でも取得可能です。

```
c = Card(u'As')
s = c.rank.val
```

なお、python2.7の場合、`rank.val`で取得すると文字コードがunicodeで、`str`を使うと文字コードが'utf-8'になることに注意してください。

理由は、Cardの最初の文字はRankを表しますが、そのクラスRankが以下のように定義されています。https://github.com/pokerregion/poker/blob/master/poker/card.py

```
class Rank(PokerEnum):
    __order__ = 'DEUCE THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN JACK QUEEN KING ACE'

    DEUCE = '2', 2
    #中略
    NINE = '9', 9
    TEN = 'T', 10
    JACK = 'J',
    QUEEN = 'Q',
    KING = 'K',
    ACE = 'A', 1
```

そして、クラスRankが承継しているクラスPokerEnumをみると、Rankの最初の値を返す`val`というプロパティが定義されています。　https://github.com/pokerregion/poker/blob/master/poker/_common.py

```
class PokerEnum(_OrderableMixin, enum.Enum):
    __metaclass__ = _PokerEnumMeta

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self._value_[0])

    def __str__(self):
        return unicode(self).encode('utf-8')

    # 中略

    @property
    def val(self):
        """The first value of the Enum member."""
        return self._value_[0]
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。やっと解決できました。